# how to add column in file txt based on filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

this is my script

```
SourceFile='/root/Document/Source/'

FND=$(find $SourceFile. -regextype posix-regex -iregex "^.*/ABCDEF_555_[0-9]{5}\.txt$")
echo $FND
#*I've tried using "awk" but haven't gotten perfect results*
```

File Name:

```
ABCDEF_555_12345.txt
ABCDEF_555_54321.txt
ABCDEF_555_11223.txt
```

*BEFORE*

```
File Content from ABCDEF_555_12345.txt:
no|name|address|pos_code
1|rick|ABC|12342
2|rock|ABC|12342
3|Robert|DEF|54321

File Content from ABCDEF_555_54321.txt:
no|id|name|city
1|0101|RIZKI|JKT
2|0102|LALA|SMG
3|0302|ROY|YGY
```

i want to append a column that shows the file name in every row starting from the 2nd, and append a column with name_file to the first and i want to change the contents of the original files.

*AFTER*

```
file: ABCDEF_555_12345.txt
no|name|address|pos_code|name_file
1|rick|ABC|12342|ABCDEF_555_12345.txt
2|rock|ABC|12342|ABCDEF_555_12345.txt
3|Robert|DEF|54321|ABCDEF_555_12345.txt

file: ABCDEF_555_54321.txt
no|id|name|city|name_file
1|0101|RIZKI|JKT|ABCDEF_555_54321.txt
2|0102|LALA|SMG|ABCDEF_555_54321.txt
3|0302|ROY|YGY|ABCDEF_555_54321.txt
```

please give me light to find a solution :))
Thanks :))

Comment: Is your requirement that you want to append a column that shows the file name in every row starting from the 2nd, and append a column with `name_file` to the first (heading) row? I assume you want to do this for every file found by your `find` command. Do you want to change the contents of the original files (not recommended), do you want to create modified copies of the files or do you only want to print the modified data. Show what you tried with `awk`. Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use awk.

If it's the first line (`NR == 1`), print the line and append `|name_file`.
For all other lines print the line and append the filename using the `FILENAME` variable:

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 {print $0 "|name_file"; next;}{print $0 "|" FILENAME;}' foo.txt
```

You can either use it with multiple files:

```sh
find . -iname "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk '
NR == 1 {print $0 "|name_file"; next;}
FRN == 1 {next;} # Skip header of next files
{print $0 "|" FILENAME;}'
```

---

My first solution used to use the [`paste`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=paste&section=1&format=html) command.

Paste allows you to concatenate files horizontally (compared to `cat` which concatenates vertically).
To achieve the following with `paste`, do:

1. first concatenate the first line of your file (`head -n1 foo.txt`) with the column header (`echo "name_file"`). The command `paste` accept the `-d` flag to define the separator between columns.
2. second, extract all lines except the first (`tail -n+2 foo.txt`) and concatenate them with as many `foo.txt` required (use a `for` loop, computing the number of lines to fill.

The solution looks like this:

```sh
paste -d'|' <(head -n1 foo.txt) <(echo "name_file")
paste -d'|' <(tail -n+2 foo.txt) <(for i in $(seq $(tail -n+2 foo.txt | wc -l)); do echo "foo.txt"; done)
```

```
no|name|address|pos_code|name_file
1|rick|ABC|12342|foo.txt
2|rock|ABC|12342|foo.txt
3|Robert|DEF|54321|foo.txt
```

However, the awk solution must be prefered because it is clearer (only one call, less process substitutions and co.), and faster.

```
$ wc -l foo.txt
100004 foo.txt

$ time ./awk.sh >/dev/null
./awk.sh > /dev/null  0,03s user 0,01s system 98% cpu 0,041 total

$ time ./paste.sh >/dev/null
./paste.sh > /dev/null  0,38s user 0,33s system 154% cpu 0,459 total
```

Comment: can you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Hi Alexis. I appriciate your paste solution, I do not believe this is the best approach. You awk solution is excellent. Here are a couple of pointers to improve it. **(1)** awk has an internal variable called `FILENAME`. This means that you do not have to use a shell variable for that. So you could translate it into `NR > 1 {print $0 "|" FILENAME}` **(2)** The standard way to process a header and skip it is using `(NR==1){...;next}`. This way you do not need to use a second condition like `NR>1`. In the end it would look like: `awk '(NR==1){print $0"| name file"; next}{print $0 "|" FILENAME}'`

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for the advices. I don't know awk that much. I update my answer.

Comment: The shortest `awk` would actually be: `awk '{print $0 "|" (NR==1?"name_file":FILENAME)}' foo.txt`

Comment: I also believe your method with `paste` could be improved by ignoring `head` and `tail` and adding a condition into your `for` loop to check if your index `i` equals 1 or not. In the current `paste` solution you are reading 6 times the file `foo.txt` (1x head, 1x paste, 1x tail, 1x paste, 1x tail, 1x wc). This could be reduced to 2 times (1x paste and 1x wc)

Comment: @kvantour Yes, your awk solution is shorter but it prevents to use it with multiple files, handling the `FNR==1` case. By the ignoring the `head` and `tail` calls will make it faster, but dirty, as `if` condition are not very easy and clear in bash...

Comment: thanks a lot @AlexisBRENON and kvantour ALL script working :)).
but, any problem...
all script make a new tail with a path
i mean like this "/root/blablabla/foo.txt"

Comment: @TsabitAbdullah See my solution which extracts the filename and modifies the files in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` and GNU `awk`:

My `find` implementation doesn't have regextype `posix-regex` and I used `posix-extended` instead, but since you got the correct results it should be fine.

```
srcdir='/root/Document/Source/'
find "$srcdir" -regextype posix-regex -iregex ".*/ABCDEF_555_[0-9]{5}\.txt$"\
    -exec awk -i inplace -v fname="{}" '
  BEGIN{ OFS=FS="|"; sub(/.*\//, "", fname) }    # set field separators / extract filename
  { $(NF+1)=NR==1 ? "name_file" : fname; print } # add header field / filename, print line
' {} \;
```

The pathname found by `find` is passed to `awk` in variable `fname`. In the `BEGIN` block the filename is extracted from the path.

The files are modified "inplace", make sure you make a backup of your files *before* running this.

Comment: thanks dud, this script its work too.. :))
but the result header n tile is not some line (entered)

Comment: @TsabitAbdullah The additional header field should be `name_file` or not?

Comment: not, header field is NAMA_FILE.
btw sorry to late answer, yesterday i going to holiday.

Comment: how to refers? I need the path, without the file name.